# Пунктуация с союзом "или" в сложноподчиненном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Одна своенравная героиня говорит: «Сама не знаю, была я замужем, или это страшный сон…»
У меня такое впечатление, что она присвоила себе лишнюю запятую перед союзом «или». Отобрать, чтобы неповадно было? ☺

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Запятая при встрече ЛИ/ЛЬ... ИЛИ, или Согласны ли Вы со словарём?](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1751684-zapjataja-pri-vstreche-li-l-ili-ili-soglasny-li-vy-so-slovarjom.html) - это мой вопрос.

Пояснения к нему:

> *Идет ли дождь, или светит солнце – ему всё равно*.
>
> Расскажите, пожалуйста, обо всех случаях (не)постановки запятой при
>   встрече этой парочки.
>
> И даже без парочки, **про одинокое "или"**:
>
> «...Запятая ставится, так как союз ИЛИ способствует членению
>   предложения на две части (о чем свидетельствует пауза между ними):
>   *"Дядя в вас влюблен, или нет?"* *"Ты меня понял, или ударить тебя?"*»

Ответ дан филологом экстра-класса, составителем учебников (в соавторстве) и методичек по русскому языку.

---

> Говорить о том, согласна я с установившимися пунктуационными
>   правилами, легко и трудно даже в таком конкретном случае, как встреча
>   в предложении ЛИ/ЛЬ с ИЛИ. Легко, ибо я, лицо частное и хорошо правила
>   пунктуации усвоившее (что, кстати, не мешает мне, а наоборот,
>   заставляет меня совершенствовать свои пунктуационные навыки
>   постоянно), естественно, могу судить со своей колокольни о том или
>   ином правиле: с одной стороны, мне ничего не стоит высказать своё
>   мнение, с другой – моё высказывание никого ни к чему не обязывает. Да
>   и смешно было бы услышать в качестве аргумента нечто вроде: «Запятую я
>   здесь не поставил(а), так как И. Р. в данном случае её ставить не
>   рекомендует». Трудно, потому что даже при моём личном несогласии с
>   правилом я должна им руководствоваться и ему следовать, ибо знаки
>   препинания для того и введены, чтобы облегчить нам процесс чтения, а
>   стоящие не на своих местах либо пропущенные, они процесс этот
>   существенно затрудняют, увеличивая время, затрачиваемое нами и на
>   чтение, и на усвоение прочитанного.
>
> Правила, связанные со встречей в предложениях ЛИ (буду использовать
>   этот вариант) с ИЛИ, касаются и конструкций с членами однородными, и
>   предложений сложных.
>
> В первом случае (с членами однородными) перед союзом ИЛИ,
>   расположившимся сразу за ЛИ или на расстоянии, запятая не ставится,
>   например:
>
> *От смущения ли или от жары Вера Николаевна испытывала дискомфорт и казалась неуверенной в себе.*
>
> *В доме ли быта или в доме культуры он был завхозом почти четверть века.*
>
> В качестве примеров из литературы художественной многие источники
>   приводят одни и те же предложения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Замечу: ничего против того, чтобы не считать ЛИ и ИЛИ в подобных
>   предложениях повторяющимся союзом, я не имею.
>
> Во втором случае (в предложениях сложных) правилами предписывается ЛИ
>   и ИЛИ считать союзами повторяющимися, а потому непременно помнить о
>   постановке запятой перед ИЛИ. Это касается:
>
> - предложений сложносочинённых (ССП);
> - предложений сложноподчинённых (СПП).
>
> Примеры приведу из компетентных источников (Справочника Лопатина,
>   Справочника по пунктуации, справочник Розенталя), процитировавших
>   русских классиков:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу внимания к следующему пассажу:

> ***И вот здесь всё нутро моё восстаёт: никак не принимаю я эти ЛИ и ИЛИ в качестве повторяющихся союзов, особенно в ССП вопросительных по
>   цели высказывания (ЦВ), ибо ЛИ/ЛЬ в них склонна рассматривать как
>   вопросительную частицу, а ИЛИ как разделительный союз. И правило бы я
>   применила здесь иное: об отсутствии запятой между частями ССП,
>   соединёнными ОДИНОЧНЫМ СОЮЗОМ, когда это СПП является
>   вопросительным.***
>
> В случае с приведённым выше СПП из «Отрочества» почти то же самое,
>   только ЛИ уже выступает в качестве союза подчинительного,
>   присоединяющего придаточное изъяснительное, а ИЛИ остаётся союзом
>   сочинительным между придаточными однородными, а потому никак не могу
>   считать эти союзы разных разрядов повторяющимися. Но как
>   законопослушная гражданка Страны русского языка принимаю сии правила,
>   просто в своей речи письменной подобных предложений не употребляю,
>   благо язык наш настолько богат, что «и без них можно обойтиться». Так
>   один чеховский персонаж написал по поводу пятен на солнце, а я его
>   слова отнесу к ЛИ и ИЛИ в предложениях сложных.
>
> Но замечу: есть и такие предложения, где ЛИ и ИЛИ поистине
>   повторяющиеся союзы, например, в приведённом Вами предложении о дожде
>   и солнце или в таких предложениях:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Но недобросовестное цитирование заставляет недоумевать. Наш уважаемый
>   Розенталь из щедринского предложения в своём справочнике цитирует
>   только часть (по слово шутила, после коего ставит точку). Но в таком
>   случае ощущается вопросительная интонация, потому и предложение
>   приобретает совершенно иной характер: ЛИ в нём, опять же на мой
>   взгляд, частица вопросительная, и перед одиночным ИЛИ запятая не
>   требуется именно на том основании, что ССП вопросительное (заметьте: у
>   писателя 3 части в предложении, а не 2! Иная структура – иные знаки).
>
> Теперь только об ИЛИ. Сей союз может соединять либо члены однородные,
>   либо части ССП, и в обоих случаях быть ОДИНОЧНЫМ или ПОВТОРЯЮЩИМСЯ.
>
> В конструкциях с членами однородными перед одиночным ИЛИ запятая не
>   нужна, перед повторяющимся ставится, но между членами однородными (это
>   дополнение касается места расположения 1-го ИЛИ и знака перед ним:
>   если союз перед 1-м членом однородным располагается, запятую ставить
>   себе дороже – ошибка обеспечена; если после 1-го – без знака не
>   обойтись:
>
> - Ваня опоздает или вовсе не придёт.
> - Ваня или опоздает, или вовсе не придёт.
> - Ваня придёт раньше назначенного времени, или опоздает, или вовсе забудет о встрече.
> - Ваня или придёт раньше назначенного времени, или опоздает, или вовсе забудет о встрече.
>
> В ССП союз ИЛИ находится между его частями, запятая перед ним
>   обязательна, кроме особых случаев:
>
> - [Виктор Иванович должен сам отправиться в эту командировку], или [наша годовая работа пойдёт насмарку].
> - Или [дождик накрапывает], или [снежок идёт], или [просто на улице пасмурно].
>
> Не ставится запятая перед ИЛИ в предложении сложном, как и перед
>   другими одиночными союзами (соединительными или разделительными),
>   если:
>
> - есть общий компонент (член второстепенный, предложение придаточное, конструкция вводная): [Только что дождь закапал] или [мелкие градинки
>     по крыше застучали]; [Вероятно, Ваня опоздает к семейному ужину] или
>     [друзья уговорят его поужинать с ними в ресторане];
> - обе части ССП по ЦВ вопросительные или побудительные или по окраске эмоциональной восклицательные: [Ты ко мне готовиться к экзамену
>     придёшь] или [мне к тебе прийти]? [Решайтесь] или [уступите дорогу
>     другим];
> - обе части ССП – предложения неопределённо-личные, где действующее(-ие) лицо(а) одно (одни) и то (те) же, или безличные, или
>     номинативные (назывные): [Тебе будет грустно] или [ему весело].
>     [Восход солнца] или [его закат].

(Ещё раз прошу Вашего внимания:)

> ***Предложения из вопроса с влюблённым дядей и с непонятым, желающим ударить за непонимание, как раз ССП с обеими вопросительными частями и
>   не требуют постановки запятой.*** Нашла я источник Вашего цитирования
>   со ссылкой на некоего Ткаченко, никому доныне неизвестное правило
>   сформулировавшего. *Если сей Ткаченко процитирован точно, скажу: это
>   человек, возомнивший, что может в русском языке устанавливать правила
>   по своему разумению. Книги, включая учебные, в наши дни может писать и
>   издавать кто угодно, благо и издательств расплодилось.* Московское
>   издательство, опубликовавшее труд Ткаченко, официальным учреждением,
>   издающим учебные пособия, не является. У меня достаточно опыта общения
>   с разными издательствами, и я знаю: в подобных учреждениях, число
>   которых неуклонно растёт (ещё бы: издание учебной литературы приносит
>   миллионные прибыли, причём не в рублях!), зачастую нет грамотных
>   редакторов и корректоров, а литература, предназначенная для обучения
>   детей, здесь издающаяся, не рецензируется никем и чаще всего не
>   проходит экспертизу. Так что господин Ткаченко как частное лицо издал
>   своё пособие, в котором изложил материал так, как это ему захотелось.
>
> Помнить надо и о пояснительном союзе ИЛИ, весь оборот с коим
>   обособляется, и о двойных названиях произведений с союзом ИЛИ.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой коммент к этому драгоценному ответу:

*Ирина Робертовна, как замечательно, что у Вас восстало нутро против несправедливости в языке! Давайте отправим эти вопрос/ответ Лопатину, Грамоте.ру и кто там ещё публикует правила и морочит головы пытающимся постичь ВМПС им. Тургенева лжепримерами. Вы так убедительно и наглядно всё разъяснили, что непременно всколыхнётся сонное болото законодателей от языка. Есть же там хоть одна живая душа?! Вот она и потормошит равнодушных коллег. А?*

Comment: @Aer! Помогите, пожа-а-алуйста! (Хнык-хнык) Не знаю, к какому берегу прибиться. Мне кажется существенным тот факт, что в приведенном мной предложении нет «ли». Действует ли в этом случае правило про ли… или… в сложноподчиненном предложении?

Comment: Лена, я на Галю отзываюсь. В процитированном ответе есть и Ваш случай: ***Не ставится запятая перед ИЛИ в предложении сложном***, как и перед другими одиночными союзами (соединительными или разделительными), если:

***есть общий компонент*** (член второстепенный, ***предложение придаточное***, конструкция вводная)...

Comment: Галина, я поняла.☺ В приведенном мною предложении одиночный союз "или", а не покалеченный "ли... или..." Спасибище! )))

Comment: А где клик по галочке - нижней, слева от ответа? Именно он называется на этом сайте спасибом! )))

Comment: но тогда мое предложение не сложноподчиненное (как написали в заголовке), а какое? С бессоюзной и сочинительной связью? О_о
(С галочками и треугольниками еще не совсем освоилась. Где-то написано о них?)

Comment: Сложноподчинённое. Главное: *Сама* ***не знаю*** - неполное, с пропущенным подлежащим, и придаточное из двух основ: ***была я замужем*** или ***это*** *страшный* ***сон***…»

Comment: А сложноподчиненные бывают без подчинительного союза?

Comment: Ох, Леночка, чтоб я была таким же теоретиком, как практиком! Выяснила, что не бывают, а сразу конвертируются в бессоюзные сложные. *...Подчинительный союз можно убрать из предложения без искажения его смысла (правда, тогда это будет уже не сложноподчиненное, а бессоюзное предложение). Исключение составляет союз-частица ли, который находится в середине придаточного предложения.*  Нужно задать "самостоятельный" вопрос о: вместо союза-частицы ли стоит союз или - как называется такой  вид сложного предложения? И повторить свой пример.

Comment: Благодарю за совет. ☺ Так и сделаю. ♥

Answer (score 2):

Вы правы: запятая не нужна.

3) В сложноподчиненном предложении с однородным подчинением: **Я напряженно думаю, справится она с этой задачей или мне следует ей помочь.**

Подробнее: [Пунктуация с союзом или в сложных предложениях](http://russkiiyazyk.ru/punktuatsiya/kogda-pered-soyuzom-ili-stavitsya-zapyataya.html)

Comment: Серж, там, куда вы нас отсылаете, предложение не содержит *ли*, те есть вы это *ли* "пририсовали" и тем самым все запутали. На самом деле сочетание  ЛИ...ИЛИ считается повторяющимся союзом и требует постановки запятой (см. ответ @Jasmin). Однако в вопросе нет *ли*, посему запятая не нужна.

Comment: М_Г , туда, куда я вас отсылал, "ли" изначально содержалось. Но дело не в этом. Там была ошибка. После того как я им написал, они убрали "ли". А я механически скопировал пример и не заметил "ли".

Comment: Там должен быть мой комментарий.  И еще: я никогда ничего не "пририсовываю". Запятая, конечно, не нужна! О чем я и  пишу в своем ответе.

Comment: Серж, я только хотел внести ясность и не хотел вас обидеть. Извините, если получилось неуклюже с моей стороны.

Comment: @– М_Г , все в порядке.

Answer (score 1):

Сама не знаю, была **ли** я замужем, **или** это страшный сон…

**По Розенталю запятая ставится**, так как союз ЛИ...ИЛИ считается повторяющимся. Надо различать союзы ЛИ...ИЛИ и ИЛИ.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139,3#pp139

4) если союзами ли…или связаны соподчиненные придаточные части, перед или ставится запятая: Трудно было понять, наступают ли это сумерки, или это тучи так непроницаемо окутали землю (Баб.).

Comment: Но ведь здесь нет повторяющегося союза. Здесь одиночный союз или.

Comment: А должен быть союз ЛИ...ИЛИ.  Мы же не говорим: "Сама не знаю, была я замужем". Частица ЛИ выражает вопрос, неуверенность, сомнение. Частица ЛИ используется, когда у нас есть косвенный вопрос без вопросительного слова.   Союз ЛИ...ИЛИ позволяет прочитать оба предложения с вопросительной интонацией.  У Розенталя есть пример, когда запятая не ставится: "Он не понял, одобряют его ИЛИ порицают" (альтернативный вопрос), но здесь односоставные предложения близки к однородным членам, ИЛИ заменяет ЛИ.  В остальных случаях запятая ставится. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_392

Comment: Поэтому, с одной стороны,  не стоит переписывать классические правила, а с другой -  желательно ориентироваться на интонацию. Хорошо бы помнить о том, что при отсутствии запятой мы имеем одну фразу, а к большинству примеров из наших классиков такая интонация не подходит, там мы явно имеем две вопросительные фразы и должны ставит запятую, соответственно.